# Матрица поворота, почему работает не так как ожидалось?

Tags: математика, матрицы, графика, геометрия

Имеется матрица вращения[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня в программе она работает корректно, поворачивает точки на заданный угол, но я не могу понять почему))
Дело в том что я попробовал повернуть точку на бумаге и перемножил вручную (координату в виде строки умножаю на матрицу), угол при этом взял 90 градусов, а результат получил как будто повернул на -90. Просмотрел в программе метод умножения координаты на матрицу, попробовал тот же опыт произвести программно, получил тот же результат: вращение в обратную сторону. Может быть кто то что то знает по этому поводу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А какие системы координат используются на бумаге и в программе?

Приведённая матрица соответствует повороту на минус 90 градусов.

Как это будет выглядеть на экране - зависит от упомянутой СК.
 Для часто используемой системы с осью OY, направленной вниз, это будет поворот против часовой стрелки.